# Different colors to each Stacked Bars in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors, bar-chart

I am trying to assign different colors to each bars of the stacked bar charts as currently there is only single color in all the four bars but trying to assign different colors to all the four bars as well the stacked value.

**Code**

```
  var margin = {
          top: 20,
          right: 160,
          bottom: 35,
          left: 30
        };

        var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var svg = d3.select("body")
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


        /* Data in strings like it would be if imported from a csv */

        var data = [{
            year: "A",
            redDelicious: "10",
            mcintosh: "5",
            color:"red",
            oranges: "19"
          }, {
            year: "B",
            redDelicious: "12",
            mcintosh: "12",
            color:"blue",
            oranges: "15"
          }, {
            year: "C",
            redDelicious: "05",
            mcintosh: "10",
            color:"green",
            oranges: "18"
          }, {
            year: "D",
            redDelicious: "14",
            mcintosh: "8",
            color:"yellow",
            oranges: "12"
          },

        ];
        $("#btn").on("click", function(){
          d3.selectAll("svg > g > g").remove();
          data[1].mcintosh = (Number(data[1].mcintosh) + 1).toString();
          console.log(1,data);
          update();
        });
        update();
  function update(){
        var orangeData = data.map(function(d) {
          return {
            year: d.year,
            oranges: +d.oranges
          }
        });
        console.log(orangeData)



        // Transpose the data into layers
        var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["redDelicious", "mcintosh"].map(function(skillset) {
          return data.map(function(d) {
            return {
              x: d.year,
              y: +d[skillset]
            };
          });
        }));
        console.log(dataset)

        // Set x, y and colors
        var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) {
            return d.x;
          }))
          .rangeRoundBands([10, width - 10], 0.02);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
            return d3.max(d, function(d) {
              return d.y0 + d.y;
            });
          })])
          .range([height, 0]);

        var colors = ["#b33040", "#edd"];
         var backcolors = ["cyan", "blue","green","gray"];


        // Define and draw axes
        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(y)
          .orient("left")
          .ticks(5)
          .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
          .tickFormat(function(d) {
            return d
          });

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(x)
          .orient("bottom");
        //  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));

        svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis);

        svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

          // Creating the Average Bar for the Semester
          svg.selectAll(".bar1").data(orangeData).enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "bar1").append("rect")
          .attr("x", function(d) {
            return x(d.year) ; // center it
          })
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand()) // make it slimmer
          .attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.oranges);
          })
          .attr("height", function(d) {
            return height - y(d.oranges);
          })
          .style("fill", function(d, i) {
            return backcolors[i];
          });



        // Create groups for each series, rects for each segment in Stacked Bar 
        var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
          .data(dataset)
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "cost")
          .style("fill", function(d, i) {
            return colors[i];
          });

        var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
          .data(function(d) {
            return d;
          })
          .enter()
          .append("rect")
          .attr("x", function(d) {
            return x(d.x)  + 20 ;
          })
          .attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.y0 + d.y);
          })
          .attr("height", function(d) {
            return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y);
          })
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand() -40 );
          }
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/hawkeye15/omwo8qbo/4/) for the same

Comment: You mean to say, you want to assign the same colors which are in the background?

Comment: Any set of different colors not necessarily those only. But definitely not the same color set